# Determine the part of speech of a number

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, text-normalization

For a given number, I want to distinguish whether it is a phone number or a quantity value, depending on the context. One idea I have right now is to figure out its part of speech, but I am having trouble doing that using NLTK.

For example: "How many books do you have? I have 911 books." In this case, 911 is a adjective, so it should be converted to "NINE HUNDRED AND ELEVEN". But in this sentence, "Can you call 911, there's an emergency!" 911 is a noun (phone number), and should be converted to "NINE ONE ONE"

When I use the tokenizer in NLTK, it only tells me that 911 is a cardinal number, but is there a way to change it so that it will give me a part of speech that's more specific? (I want noun, adjective, or pronoun)

Comment: I would look for the trunk prefix if possible, in the UK and a lot of other countries all phone numbers start with 0. However with quantities people don't tend to use a 0 prefix unless the figure is less than one and includes a decimal point.
911 and 7/11 are special cases, I think you'll just need to use a lookup table for them.

Comment: Thanks @InvertedLlama but the problem I want to solve is to determine whether 911 or 7/11 means a value or the named entity in a particular sentence context. A look up table would only work if I want all the appearance of 7/11 to be read as "seven eleven", but in cases like "I have 7/11 of a pie left" I would want it to be read as "seven elevenths" or something like that.